# What does it mean "We use C++/C as backend"

Tags: architecture, backend

What does it mean when people say we use C++/C as backend. 
Lets say facebook for instance whereas frontend is php.
How can one bind any other lang to c++/c?

My context is web.

For instance user using a web site...Its agreeable to think that o/p is generated by php using templating..

but how is database/caching/web services/business logic etc implemented in c++/c

Comment: When two applications communicate over a protocol, lets say TCP, the languages don't really matter (though there may be subtleties). This is what you probably think of when you say "bind". A protocol itself is just a means to communicate (and a bunch of rules to do so).

Comment: agreed...this is the case with web services where server 1 is httpd+php and other is tomcat+servlets...kind of B2B...But whats the case inside same application where there is only 1 server..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most languages have some way to connect to external components.  For example, PHP has the [COM constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php), which allows you to access any OLE-compatible component from within PHP.  That component is probably a DLL, and could easily be written in C or C++.

Additionally, a well-designed system will consist of layers that are separated as cleanly as possible.  So, for example, the view engine could potentially communicate with the business-logic layer via web services, or via an Enterprise Service Bus.  In this type of scenario, the two components need not be written in compatible languages at all, so long as they can make or consume web service requests.

Comment: ok thats the case with windows i guess..what about linux platform

Comment: POSIX support; the ability to call executables using `shell_exec`, `proc_open`, or `system`; the ability to call web services -- PHP is designed to interact with other components.

Comment: Does this mean that I will write a c/c++ code and put it in file...and using posix..I invoke that file+methods..is this called "having c/c++ as backend"?

Comment: It could mean that.  "Having c/c++ as backend" just means that some of the parts that don't face the user -- the business logic and data manipulation -- are written, somehow, in c/c++.  As I say, that could mean calling a shared library, calling a web service, making a system call to an executable, calling a wrapper that someone has created that wraps a c/c++ API with PHP code, etc.  There are many ways to accomplish this; it's a standard practice.

Comment: thanks...it is somewhat clearer for me now...can you please comment on database layer? Is it possible to use php/any scripting lang. just to throw stuff at browser and rest everything is done by native languages like c/c++?

Answer (score 4):

*"backend"* and *"frontend"* are meaningless words when used out of context. Each abstraction layer in your application can have frontends and backends.

To answer the question, it only means they use c/c++ at an arbitrary point.

Answer (score 2):

**Frontend** is usually the application that is exposed to user/world (a windows application, a web application or a web service).

**Backend** is usually the application which contains all logic (do calculations, work with the DB) etc.